# How do you find a point between two complex numbers that are X% between them?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have two complex numbers Q and R which represent the RF S-parameters at two frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$.  I would like to do a linear approximation of an S-parameter at some frequency between $f_1$ and $f_2$ called $f_3$.

I know I can find the midpoint in the complex plane if $f_3=\frac{f_2-f_1}{2}$ as follows:

$\frac{Q_r+R_r}{2} + \frac{Q_i+R_i}{2} i$

But if $f_3$ is not at the midpoint, can I scale the midpoint equation as a percentage distance ("$p$") between Q and R to find the new complex S-parameter ("$S$") like this?

1. $p = \frac{f_3-f_1}{f_2-f_1}$
2. $S = p(Q_r+R_r) + p(Q_i+R_i) i$

It seems reasonable because when $p=\frac{1}{2}$ this is the midpoint equation, but I'm not able to convince myself that this is the generalized form because when:

- $f_1=145.5$
- $f_2=147.0$
- $f_3=146.0$
- $Q = 0.460 + 0.473i$
- $R = 0.464 + 0.473i$
- $p = 0.33$

then I get $S = 0.2772+0.2838i$

... but shouldn't the value be pretty close between 0.460 and 0.464?

- Is this right?
- Why/why not?
- If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: It is right....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, but its not!  See the others' answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point that is "$p$ percent of the way from $Q$ to $R$" is given by
$$
(1-p)Q+pR.
$$
(Try some examples to convince yourself that it's true.)
This formula holds in the real numbers, in $\Bbb R^2$, in $\Bbb C$, and indeed in any vector space over the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A general way to interpolate two points $x,y$ is to define a line between them
$$
f(t)=t(x-y)+y,\; t\in[0,1]\\
f(0)=x,f(1)=y
$$
Then, make $x,y$ your two ending complex numbers $Q,R$ set $t$ as your proportion $p$ you get the point $p$ ratio way there.
$$
f(p)=p(x-y)+y
$$